# bgStrecher background in slider showing gap on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, resize, slider

i am going to ask for help about my project which i have done recently.

http://www.coffeefinance.com.au/

i search alot but did not find any thing. in this site i use slider with bg-stretcher on home page. problem is that when i resize the window the bg stretcher do not work. and its showing a gap. here is a screenshot attached.

[image: Screen Shot Browser]

Its in All browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after very looking i find fixed it with:

```
margin-left:0;
```

Thanks to all for give No comments

Comment: Thats the spirit! Glad you found the answer. +1 for posing the answer.

Comment: Thanks Shiham. its appreciated